# Start Multiple java TimerTasks at the same time

Tags: java, performance, scheduled-tasks, timertask

Is it possible to schedule multiple TimerTasks such that they all begin at the same time and if so how would I do it?  In particular I would like to initiate these tasks at the same exact time so that the relative time difference between each task is as specified (I want to be as accurate as possible).

```
toneIntervalClock.scheduleAtFixedRate(tonePlayerTask, 250, 5000);
startRecordingClock.scheduleAtFixedRate(startRecordingTask,0,5000);
stopRecordingClock.scheduleAtFixedRate(stopRecordingTask, 1000, 5000);
```

Also would it be better practice to use the same Util Timer to schedule each task?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system will try to make `scheduleAtFixedRate` tasks fire with low jitter, but you don't ever get any guarantees with concurrency.

Your approach of trying to initialize all of the tasks and then run them is a decent one. The only suggestion I would make is to use `Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)`, since then you don't have any jitter in between your `schedule` calls and can start them all from a fixed time reference.

Comment: Thank you.  I figured that there would be drift as time goes on; I just wanted to make sure that they start at the same time.  Do you know if it would be better practice (more accurate) to schedule each task using the same clock or does it not matter?

Comment: *In fixed-rate execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the scheduled execution time of the initial execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up."*

Comment: Correct.  I was just wondering if using different clock variables (ie toneIntervalClock, startRecordingClock, stopRecordingClock) would have any affect.  My intuition is no since I am using a fixed-rate execution, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: BTW using date to make sure that the start time is the same is a very good idea.  I hadn't thought that.  Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I had missed that you misnamed `Timer`s as `Clock`; please try to make the names match up for clarity. Again from the Javadoc: *Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up" and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task finally completes.*

Comment: Whoops, yes I did.  So what I am doing is correct then.  If i used the same util timer to schedule each task then each would run sequentially in the same thread (I want these to tasks to be able to run concurrently since they overlap at times)